# writing a thread(educational purpose)

Tags: multithreading

Sorry if this is a  duplicate...
I have a task to write a thread. And the question is - what a good thread class should contain. I looked through Java implementation and some other, but since it is just an educational project, I wouldn't want to make it too complex. If you can tell or point me to source witch contains required information, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What language are you using? What platform?

Comment: What do you mean by writing a thread? Do you mean starting a thread and executing some task on this thread?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - sorry, i meant writing a class, which would operate with single thread (smth like a thread wrapper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple thread class consists of following along with threadManager class for easier management of multiple threads

### Thread class:

Constructor

function to execute thread

Check if thread is running and process thread's output, if any is present. Returns 
TRUE if the thread is still executing, FALSE if it's finished.

Wait until the thread exits

### ThreadManager class:

Constructor

Add an existing thread to the manager queue.

Remove a thread from the manager queues.

Process all threads. Returns the number of threads that are still running.

Create and start a new thread. Returns the ID assigned to the thread or FALSE on error.

Remove a finished thread from the internal queue and return it. Returns FALSE if there are no threads that have completed execution.

Answer (score 0):

On the highest level of abstraction you can think about the thread as a combinration of:

1. Finite-state machine to represent thread's state
2. Queue of tasks to proceed
3. Scheduler which can manage threads (start, pause, notify etc ..). Scheduler can be OS level scheduler or  some custom scheduler, for example, on the VM level - so called "green threads".

To be more specific, I would recommend to look at Erlang VM. Sources are available online and you can go through their implementantion for "green threads" which are extremely lightweight.

[Erlang Downloads](http://www.erlang.org/download.html)